# How to make one maven repository not use proxy

Tags: java, maven

I have configured `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` to use use proxy and I have several repositories in it. Is there posiblity that one of repository don't use proxy?

Part of settings.xml

```
<settings ...>
...
    <proxies>
            <proxy>
              <id>...</id>
              <active>true</active>
              <protocol>http</protocol>
              <host>...</host>
              <port>80</port>
              <username>...</username>
              <password>...</password>
              <nonProxyHosts>...</nonProxyHosts>
            </proxy>
  </proxies>
  <profiles>
       <profile>
             <id>...</id>
             <activation>
                  <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
             </activation>
             <repositories>
                  <repository>           <!-- there is more repositories like this -->
                      <id>...</id>
                      <name>...</name>
                      <url>...</url>
                      <releases>
                          <enabled>false</enabled>
                      </releases>
                      <snapshots>
                          <enabled>true</enabled>
                      </snapshots>
                  </repository>
               .....
               </repositories>
            </profile>
    </profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>snapshots</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Comment: Can you share your `settings.xml` (or at least, the relevant parts of it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bypass the proxy while accessing to a remote repository, just add its domain name or IP address to the `<nonProxyHosts>` tag of the proxy definition. More info in the [Maven doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html).